# TLV Parameters in Kannel

Tags: smpp, kannel, tlv

My SMS service provider asked me to set the below TLV parameters while connecting to him over SMPP:

- PRICEPOINT (0x1400)
- PRODUCT (0x1401)
- PARTNER ROLE ID (0x1402)

How to configure the same in Kannel as it is the first time for me using this SMPP client app, I set the below data in Kannel.conf file, but when I pushed/sent a message, the gateway didn't feel the TLV which I have set.

```
group = smpp-tlv
name = PRICEPOINT
tag = 0x1400
type = integer
length = 4
smsc-id = SMSC01

group = smpp-tlv
name = PRODUCT
tag = 0x1401
type = integer
length = 4
smsc-id = SMSC01

group = smpp-tlv
name = PARTNERROLEID
tag = 0x1402
type = integer
length = 4
smsc-id = SMSC01
```

But in the live TCP trace, I didn't find it:

[image]

Comment: Also, I need to know if I should send something in **SendSms** HTTP callback or just set the TLV params in **Kannel.conf** only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did the right thing with the configuration but what it does is that it simply informs Kannel as to what possible TLV parameters exist for the SMSC.

To actually use them, you have to set the values in the sendsms call in a `meta-data` parameter formatted like this `?smsc-type?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3...` You must take into account that when constructing this string, the smsc-type, the keys and the values must be urlencoded, and then the whole resulting string has to be urlencoded again.

In your case it would look something like this: `http://host:port/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=user&password=password&to=recipientphone&from=senderphone&text=content&smsc=smsc&meta-data=%3Fsmpp%3FPRICEPOINT%3D1%26PRODUCT%3D2%26PARTNERROLEID%3D3`.

The `%3Fsmpp%3FPRICEPOINT%3D1%26PRODUCT%3D2%26PARTNERROLEID%3D3` in the example is urlencoded `?smpp?PRICEPOINT=1&PRODUCT=2&PARTNERROLEID=3`.

Here's the relevant section in the documentation: http://kannel.org/download/1.4.4/userguide-1.4.4/userguide.html#AEN6370

Comment: Many thanks, it works now ... I was just wondered as I dealt with an SP earlier and it was enough to have the TLV in Kannel.conf file. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: May I have your assistance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422813/smsc-is-having-multiple-connections-with-client-but-client-has-one-connection) please