# SMSC has many connections with the client, but the client has only one single connection

Tags: tcp, sms, sms-gateway, smpp, kannel

First off, there a similar question with the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422813/smsc-is-having-multiple-connections-with-client-but-client-has-one-connection), but there is no answer, so I rewrote the question once again in more detail.

I am connected to an SMSC, and I noticed that there are a lot of messages are not delivered to us, we asked the SMSC to check the routing and it was fine, but SMSC noticed that there are too many connections established from your side to his side, although, we have one single connection only.

I was using NowSMS SMPP Client application to handle the connectivity, then, the SMSC asked me to change the application although I was thinking that NowSMS had no issues as I am using it 7 years ago, however, I asked NowSMS's team to investigate by opening a [support ticket](https://support.nowsms.com/discus/messages/1/73821.html).

Later, I had to change NowSMS and install Kannel on a new Linux machine, after getting connected over Kannel to the SMSC, we got the same issue once again, and when I read all Kannel's logs, I found **"System error (104): Connection reset by peer"** which makes me, logically, to open a new connection with the SMSC. Accordingly, I suggested to have a live TCP trace from both sides at the same time, and I found the below packet in Wireshark trace file:
[image]

As you see, **this is a RST/ACK from SMSC to me** without requesting RST or anything from my side, and when I asked them why do you send RST/ACK or why do you RST the connection, I didn't get any useful answere, but they told me to read more about the RST/ACK and RST and I have no idea about networking, but when I read, I found that I had no control on RST connection as there was no requests from my side to the SMSC asking for the same. They always guid me to this [post](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/why-do-i-see-a-rst-ack-packet-instead-of-a-rst-packet/2017#2017) and what I see that it doesn't belong to me.

**NOW**: I just need to know what should I do or what should I ask whom about? As, I asked the Data Center's team about the same, and they confirmed that the VPN between me and the SMSC works normally without any exceptions. I believe, that there is no issue in application layer, but I cannot recognize the root of the issue.

**P.S.** Kannel's log file, and both TCP Trace file are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/57xky5h2rneb0oe/TCP_Trace_Log_Files.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

Ask them to activate the Enquire link packet in order to drop inactive connections. It's clearly a problem from their side.

Comment: Add more details.

Comment: This should fix the problem as @Bob mentioned.

Comment: @Bob .. I will ask the SP about that, hope this solves the issue. But I want to know more about that, do you mean that he has to drop every connection doesn't send enquire links and keep only the one which sends the enquire link?

Comment: @Bob, I asked the SP and they have replied that the mentioned option is enabled already, and the weird point is the old connections still send Enquire Links, although, it is closed from my side, so, I think I have a network problem ... what do you think based on your experience?

Comment: @SteveFest, What are the details which you want to know further?

Comment: @Edmond, this didn't fix the issue, any other suggestions?

Comment: @AhmedNegm Imagine you are a visitor who has no ideas about the issue, and you suddenly put an answer. Good, Bob wrote an answer, that can **help the author**, but **future visitors** also wants to know more if they have no ideas.

Comment: **PART 1** @SteveFest, First off, thanks a lot for your interest. Well ... I have a virtual server and this server has many connections over VPNs to many service providers, all is working perfectly 7 years ago, one of these SP which I connected recently, I got an issue with him, what is the issue? The issue is that I dropped some messages (MO), and when I asked them, they told me that they delivered the messages successfully to me, but I didn't get them, after further investigation, they told me that my server still communicating while the connection is dropped/closed from their side, so ...

Comment: **PART 2** @SteveFest, ... so, they have many connections established from my side, and they delivered the message to the first one which is actually closed by both sides, but I don't know why it is still communicating .. I know that the issue couldn't be solved in this way, but I just wanna any suggestions in order to check, like Bob did earlier, he suggested to check Enquire Links and I did, but it was not the issue

Comment: @SteveFest, if it is still unclear for you, just lemme know the missing part for you and I will clarify

Comment: @AhmedNegm *Edit your post*. No one can see clearly in comments.

Comment: @AhmedNegm, how did you solve your issue? I'm fearing that we're dealing with the same SP (TMW), I knew from the IP ... your help is much appreciated as this is driving us crazy

Comment: Unfortunately, they didn't help us there, so, we had to ask them about a stable provider who works with them, then we got SMSs through that provider. Don't expect changing anything from their side... Hopeless case!!

Comment: I see... I'm starting to think the same thing... thanks